# Fit and evaluate a second order transition matrix (Markov Process) in R?

Tags: r, markov-chains

I am trying to build a **second-order Markov Chain model**, now I am try to find transition matrix from the following data.

```
dat<-data.frame(replicate(20,sample(c("A", "B", "C","D"), size = 100, replace=TRUE)))
```

Now I know how to fit the first order Markov transition matrix using the function `markovchainFit(dat)` in  `markovchain` package.

Is there any way to fit the second order transition matrix?

How do evaluate the Markov Chain models? i.e. Should I choose the first order model or second order model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should produce a Markov chain transition matrix to any lag order that you wish.

```
dat<-data.frame(replicate(20,sample(c("A", "B", "C","D"), size = 100, replace=TRUE)))

Markovmatrix <- function(X,l=1){
  tt <- table(X[,-c((ncol(X)-l+1):ncol(X))] , c(X[,-c(1:l)]))
  tt <- tt / rowSums(tt)
  return(tt)
}


Markovmatrix(as.matrix(dat),1)
Markovmatrix(as.matrix(dat),2)
```

where `l` is the lag.

e.g. 2nd order matrix, the output is:

```
         A         B         C         D
  A 0.2422803 0.2185273 0.2446556 0.2945368
  B 0.2426304 0.2108844 0.2766440 0.2698413
  C 0.2146119 0.2716895 0.2123288 0.3013699
  D 0.2480000 0.2560000 0.2320000 0.2640000
```

As for how to test what order model.    There are several suggestions.  One put forward by Gottman and Roy (1990) in their introductory book to Sequential Analysis is to use **information value**.  There is a chapter on that - most of the chapter is available online.

You can also perform a **likelihood-ratio chi-Square** test.  This is very similar to a chi square test in that you are comparing observed to expected frequencies of transitions.   However, the formula is as follows:

[image]

The degrees of freedom are the square of the number of codes minus one.  In your case you have 4 codes, so (4-1)^2 = 9.  You can then look up the associated p-value.

I hope this helps.